# How to use inner layout in DataBinding in android

Tags: android, data-binding

I use databinding in my application. I create a layout and I also include a layout but when I use want to use my included layout varible I can't find him.

Here my Java class:-

```
    public class CancelCase extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CancelCaseBinding mBinding;

    private static final String TAG = CancelCase.class.getSimpleName();
    private Context context = null;


    private AppCompatImageView imgViewBack;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // initialization context
        context = this;

        // Inflate the layout for this activty
        mBinding =  DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.cancel_case);

        mBinding.world1.



       // MainBinding binding = MainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());


      //  setTypeface();

    }
    private void setTypeface(){

    }
}
```

here my main layout.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="auth"
            type="com.octalsoftaware.archi.viewmodals.AuthViewModel" />
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/whitecolor"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/world1"
            layout="@layout/customtoolbar"/>


        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/txt_submit"
            android:layout_below="@+id/world1">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_patientname"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:text="Linder William"
                    android:textColor="@color/blackcolor"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_cancelcase"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
                    android:background="@drawable/blue_bg"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="@dimen/_15sdp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_cancelcases"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/cancel_case"
                        android:textColor="@color/whitecolor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_selectonly"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        android:text="@string/select_only_one"
                        android:textColor="@color/whitecolor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_13sdp" />

                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_beforeinducation"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/checkboxbackgroundcolor"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/checkbox_before"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:button="@drawable/checkbox_select"
                        android:checked="true"
                        android:padding="@dimen/_15sdp"
                        android:text="@string/before_induction"
                        android:textColor="@color/checkboxtextcolor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_afterinducation"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/whitecolor"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/checkbox_after"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:background="@color/whitecolor"
                        android:button="@drawable/checkbox_select"
                        android:checked="true"
                        android:padding="@dimen/_15sdp"
                        android:text="@string/after_induction"
                        android:textColor="@color/checkboxtextcolor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp" />


                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_reason"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
                    android:background="@drawable/blue_bg"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="@dimen/_15sdp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_reason"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/reason"
                        android:textColor="@color/whitecolor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_selectallapply"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        android:text="@string/reason_select_all_that_apply"
                        android:textColor="@color/whitecolor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_13sdp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_system"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/checkboxbackgroundcolor"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/checkbox_system"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:button="@drawable/checkbox_select"
                        android:checked="true"
                        android:padding="@dimen/_15sdp"
                        android:text="@string/system"
                        android:textColor="@color/checkboxtextcolor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_medical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/whitecolor"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/checkbox_medical"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:background="@color/whitecolor"
                        android:button="@drawable/checkbox_select"
                        android:checked="true"
                        android:padding="@dimen/_15sdp"
                        android:text="@string/medical"
                        android:textColor="@color/checkboxtextcolor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp" />


                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:background="@color/checkboxbackgroundcolor"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/checkbox_patient"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:button="@drawable/checkbox_select"
                        android:checked="true"
                        android:padding="@dimen/_15sdp"
                        android:text="@string/patient"
                        android:textColor="@color/checkboxtextcolor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_submit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_bg"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_12sdp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/_12sdp"
            android:text="@string/submit"
            android:textColor="@color/whitecolor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</layout>
```

Here my include layout:-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/whitecolor">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/toggle_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbarheading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/blackcolor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp" />


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_1sdp" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I see many answers but I can't find right solution.

Comment: please go through https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#includes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `layout` tag in your `customtoolbar.xml` file

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</layout>
```

Comment: Thanks @sifat  I forget use layout tag.